# Using CellDirtyStateChanged event with CheckBoxColumns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code that I am using in order to get the total count of employees selected within a datagridview.
I want it to calculate as soon as a user checks a check box or when a user unchecks it.

```
 private void dgvEmployeesToProcess_CellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dgvEmployeesToProcess.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
                {
                    txtNoOfEmpToProcess.Text = string.Empty;

                    int count = 0;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvEmployeesToProcess.Rows)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[4];

                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(checkBox.Value) == true)
                        {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    // show total count in textbox
                    txtNoOfEmpToProcess.Text = count.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The problem that I am having is that when I check the checkbox in row[0], ie. the first, `checkBox.Value` is always null and count = 0. When I click on a second checkbox, count = 1 and so forth. 
What do I need to do in order to get the count correct? Do I need to use something other than `CellDirtyStateChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line at the start of `dgvEmployeesToProcess_CellDirtyStateChanged`:

```
dgvEmployeesToProcess.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

This will commit the changes (in example check/uncheck a particular column) so you will get the actual result.